# How to order Date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format in SQLITE

Tags: database, sqlite, date

I'm using this query to order dates but its not sorting properly as my dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format in sqlite database.

```
Select p.id,c.Name as Calendar,p.PartName,p.MaintenanceDate from CalendarParts_Table p inner join Calendars_Table as c on c.id=p.Calendar order by CASE WHEN p.MaintenanceDate=" " or p.MaintenanceDate is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,date(p.MaintenanceDate,'%d/%m/%y')
```

I have also tried some other queries but nothing working for me.
I'm getting this result:
[image: This is the result of query. The dates are not properly ordered]

Comment: Change the format of the dates to YYYY-MM-DD, which is comparable and the only valid text date format for SQLite.

Comment: The format I'm using is more reliable for the client. Is there any custom code to sort date in this format?